# New to C++ having issues with output format

Tags: c++, output

I am new to C++, the issue im having at the moment is that when I ask the user a question I would like a space after that question but can't get one to appear, also my output comes out spaced out due to this or with words missing.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string movie_name;
    string lines = "-------------------------------";
    int adult_ticket_sold, child_ticket_sold;
    double gross_profit, theater_gross_profit, distributor_gross_profit;
    const float adult_ticket_price = 20;
    const float child_ticket_price = 10;
    const double theater_income_rate = .4;
    const double distributor_income_rate = .6;
    cout << "Project 1\n";
    cout << "Written by: billy bill\n";
    cout << lines << endl;
    cout << "Box Office Entry\n";
    cout << lines << endl;
    cout << "Enter the name of the movie: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, movie_name);

    cout << "Enter the amount of adult tickets sold: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> adult_ticket_sold;

    cout << "Enter the amount of children tickets sold: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> child_ticket_sold;


    gross_profit = (adult_ticket_sold * adult_ticket_price) + (child_ticket_sold * child_ticket_price);
    theater_gross_profit = theater_income_rate * ((adult_ticket_sold * adult_ticket_price) + (child_ticket_sold * child_ticket_price));
    distributor_gross_profit = distributor_income_rate * gross_profit;

    cout << lines << endl;
    cout << "Summary: Movie Income Distribution\n";
    cout << lines << endl;

    cout << "The movie:" << movie_name << endl;
    cout << "This is how much the theater made: " << theater_gross_profit << endl;
    cout << "The distributor gross profit is: " << distributor_gross_profit << endl;

    cout << lines << endl;
    cout << "End of Project 1";
    return 0;
}
```

my output comes out like this:

```
Project 1
Written by: billy bill
-------------------------------
Box Office Entry
-------------------------------
Enter the name of the movie:the boy that lived
 Enter the amount of adult tickets sold:10
 Enter the amount of children tickets sold:10
 --------
-----------------------
Summary: Movie Income Distribution
-------------------------------
The movie:he boy that lived
This is how much the theater made: 40
The distributor gross profit is: 60
-------------------------------
End of Project 1
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to add cin.ignore() after every question and I added spaces to the questions asked to the user cout << "Enter the name of the movie: "; this just seems to make everything worse

Comment: This looks like it should have been an OOP assignment. Or least employ some functions.

Comment: If you're not seeing the spaces after the question, that's surprising. It would likely mean that you didn't save and recompile. What do you know about `std::cin.ignore()`? Your application of it makes little sense.

Comment: I have compiled and run this and I see the spaces.

Comment: I also see the same calculation being done multiple times. Why not use the variable that holds the result of the calculation the first time you ran it? Also, the term "gross profit" is an oxymoron. Profits are, by definition, a net value.

Comment: I know it;s used to ignore a certain amount of characters or \n so i threw it in there to try and fix my output

Comment: Demonstrating the formatting problem should not take more than max 5 lines of code.

Comment: You only need `cin.ignore();` between a formatted extraction `>>` and `getline`. They way you have it spread everywhere will result in losing the first character of some input. It might be prefereble to only use `getline` and then use a `stringstream` to parse numerical data.

Comment: "threw it in there" is exactly the problem. You know what it does, so that's good. What you're missing is *when* it should be applied. In the case of this program, never.

Comment: If the statement is always `std::cout << lines << std::endl;`, why not just add `\n` to `lines`?

Comment: @sweenish I did not know I could do that, thank you

Comment: @Chris I'm using Clion but when I use what our professor recommended I do see the spaces, not sure why

Comment: @sweenish so far this homework is based on the first 3 chapters in our textbook, do functions in C++ work similar to the ones in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### `std::getline` and `std::cin >> number` do not play well together

Using `std::getline` and `std::cin >> number` in the same program can cause problems.

1. `std::getline` extracts and discards the newline character at the end of a line, while `std::cin >> number` does not.
2. By default, `std::cin >> number` skips over blank lines to find a number, while `getline` does not skip over blank lines to find a non-blank line. It just inputs and returns the blank line.

If you keep track of these issues, you can mix them. If you want to use `std::getline`, but the prior input used `std::cin >> number`, you need to get rid of the newline that is still waiting to be input, before calling `std::getline`.

You can use `std::ignore` for this, but not the way you have. `std::ignore()` discards only one character. That will work if the newline is the next character in the stream, but it will fail if newline is preceded by spaces or other characters. You can get around this by ignoring a large number of characters, but it may be easier just to call `std::getline` twice, and discard the value returned by the first one.

###### Don't use `std::ignore` unless you need to

When I ran your program, this is the output I got:

```
Project 1
Written by: billy bill
-------------------------------
Box Office Entry
-------------------------------
Enter the name of the movie: Oppenheimer
Enter the amount of adult tickets sold: 100
Enter the amount of children tickets sold: 100
-------------------------------
Summary: Movie Income Distribution
-------------------------------
The movie:ppenheimer
This is how much the theater made: 400
The distributor gross profit is: 600
-------------------------------
End of Project 1
```

The first problem I noticed was the missing `O` in `Oppenheimer`. That occurred because you called `std::ignore();` before calling `std::getline`. That ignores one character: the `O`. Deleting the call to `std:ignore` fixes the problem:

```cpp
    cin.ignore();   // Delete this.
    getline(cin, movie_name);
```

###### Improper calculation of gross profit

In the example above, the sale of 100 adult tickets generated (100 * $20.00) = $2000, while the sale of 100 child tickets generated (100 * $10.00) = $1000. Gross income was $3000. The 60%/40% split should give $1800 to the distributor and $1200 to the theater.

The output only shows $600 for the distributor and $400 for the theater. What gives?

Once again, `std::ignore` is the problem. After `std::getline`, there is no newline waiting on the input stream to be discarded. `std::getline` has already discarded it.

By calling `std::ignore` right before `std::cin >> adult_ticket_sold;`, the program discards the `1` in the value `100`, leaving `00` as the value for `adult_ticket_sold`.

The fix is to delete the call to `std::ignore`.

```
    cin.ignore();  // Delete this
    cin >> adult_ticket_sold;
```

Looking a little more, I realized the the other other call to `std::ignore` is not needed. It can also be deleted. Although the preceding call to `std::cin >> adult_ticket_sold;` has left a newline in the input stream, there is no need to ignore it. The subsequent call to `cin >> child_ticket_sold;` will automatically skip over it.

With all calls to `std::ignore` removed, the output looks good:

```
Project 1
Written by: billy bill
-------------------------------
Box Office Entry
-------------------------------
Enter the name of the movie: Oppenheimer
Enter the amount of adult tickets sold: 100
Enter the amount of children tickets sold: 100
-------------------------------
Summary: Movie Income Distribution
-------------------------------
The movie:Oppenheimer
This is how much the theater made: 1200
The distributor gross profit is: 1800
-------------------------------
End of Project 1
```

###### With few exceptions, professionals do not use `using namespace std;`

There are drawbacks to `using namespace std;`. See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Your textbook probably should not be teaching you to use it.

Instead, pros just type `std::` every time they need to reference a name from the Standard Library. That is why I have used `std::getline`, `std::cin`, and so on, in this answer.

Unless your professor gets mad, you should do the same thing.

Comment: A really easy-understanding, friendly and detailed answer for beginners.